# Keep two picture alligned horizontally while having a formatted paragraph next to them

Tags: css, paragraph

I am building a website, and I have two images which the size is 300x250 if you need it. My question is, I want the pictures aligned horizontally and to the right have a stylized paragraph (title with bullet points below)

My HTML

```
<div class = "mainthing">
  <div class = "pilli">
    <img class="pillipic" src="f..../pilli.jpg">
    when i add text here with a ["br"] or using ["pre"] it changes second picture locaiton.
  </div>
  <div class="shaun">
    <img class="shaunpic" src="../shaun.jpg">
  </div>
  want the second paragraph to go here to right of the second image
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.mainthing {
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  margin-right: 20vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

}

.pillipic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.shaunpic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

I have tried several different things but it always changes the second picture location. I would appreciate any help.  The reason I used the vh/vw for the main `div` is there is a separate header on the website that has buttons as well as the left side. I have that working it is just this current problem giving me trouble.

Comment: are you wanting the text below each image?  Or are you wanting the text next to each image but have each image on the same line rather than having 1 image break below the other?

Comment: From the limited description of your desired output, it may be helpful to just  wrap your text in an element, then give all of your elements (images and div containing paragraph) `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Yes I want the images on the same line. With the text aligned with the corresponding image to the right of it  not below.  The answer Michael gave is the one i think will work. Sorry, I wasn't more specific in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Give `float: right` for `.shaunpic`:

```
.shaunpic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

Something like this:

```css
.mainthing {
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  margin-right: 20vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

}

.pillipic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.shaunpic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}

.pilli, .shaun {clear: both;}
```

```html
<div class = "mainthing">
  <div class = "pilli">
    <img class="pillipic" src="//placehold.it/50x50">
    when i add text here with a ["br"] or using ["pre"] it changes second picture locaiton.
  </div>
  <div class="shaun">
    <img class="shaunpic" src="//placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  want the second paragraph to go here to right of the second image
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this - I think this is what you want:

HTML:

```
<div class="mainthing">
    <div class="pilli">
        <img class="pillipic" src="f..../pilli.jpg">
            when i add text here with a or using it changes second picture locaiton.
    </div>
    <div class="shaun">
        <img class="shaunpic" src="../shaun.jpg">
            want the second paragraph to go here to right of the second image
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainthing {
    margin-top: 20vh;
    margin-left: 20vw;
    margin-bottom: 20vh;
    margin-right: 20vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.pilli {
    /* ADDED THIS */
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.pillipic {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
.shaun {
    /* ADDED THIS */
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.shaunpic {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/11tdzx50/2/)

As for placing a bullet next to the text - simply use (ALT + 7).

Answer (score 0):

I rather to use ul > li structure for this type of listing. 
Then you can specify width for "li", put "img" and "p" inside and also set their width and give floating or display: inline-block. 
In this case you are sure that nothing will crash your structure. 
Of course this is a general outline.
Cheers :).